# getting an error while converting '11-1' to INT in sql server

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am not able to convert '11-1' to INT in sql server, the result should be 10.
i tried with convert and cast but getting an error.

Comment: if you mean you are basically doing `CAST('11-1' AS INT)` then that will clearly complain. It is a string not an integer equation.

Comment: How to handle this case?

Comment: what is the logic to convert it on 10 ??

Comment: @ZaynulAbadinTuhin 11-1 = 10

Comment: @arahman . . . You would need to use dynamic SQL.

Comment: @GirishMulgund, what is the source of the 11-1 value? Is that a table column?

Comment: yes that is the logic. but the column i am having is of varchar

Comment: @GirishMulgund, it would help if you specified the code you tried in your question to avoid the additional comment Q&A.

Comment: Be wary about answers that accept `0; SHUTDOWN; --` as a value as well, and will happily proceed to turn off your server. In general, this kind of evaluation is best done *outside* SQL Server, or (at worst) with a CLR function that can do proper parsing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As has been discussed `'11-1'` can't be converted to an `int` because it's a `varchar` representing a `numerical` expression.

The only way to reliably derive an expression stored as a `varchar` is by using dynamic SQL, which, has it own problems; specifically SQL injection.

**Assuming** that your data is coming from a table, and that these `varchar` expressions only contain simple arithmetic, you could do something like this:

```
CREATE TABLE dbo.test (ID int IDENTITY(1,1),
                       varcharExpression varchar(20));
INSERT INTO dbo.test (varcharExpression)
VALUES('11-1'),('12*2'),('2+9'),('15/3'),
      ('2^4'), --not supported in this example. SQL Server doesn't use ^, it uses POWER: POWER(2,4)
      ('DROP TABLE dbo.test;'); --Intentional example of an injection attempt.

GO
DECLARE @SQL nvarchar(MAX);

SET @SQL = STUFF((SELECT NCHAR(10) + N'UNION ALL' + NCHAR(10) +
                         N'SELECT ' + CONVERT(varchar(6),ID) + N' AS ID,' + NCHAR(10) +
                         N'       ' + CASE WHEN varcharExpression NOT LIKE '%[^0-9\-+*/]%' ESCAPE '\' THEN varcharExpression ELSE N'NULL' END + N' AS ExpressionValue'
                  FROM dbo.test
                  ORDER BY ID ASC
                  FOR XML PATH(N'')),1,10,N'') + ';';
PRINT @SQL;
EXEC sp_executesql @SQL;
GO
DROP TABLE dbo.test
```

Answer (score 2):

`'11-1'` is a string and can't be converted to `INT`. You can do that as

```
SELECT (CAST (11-1) AS INT)
```

Or by using Dynamic SQL as

```
DECLARE @SQL NVARCHAR(MAX) = N'SELECT 11-1';

EXECUTE sp_executesql @SQL;
```

Or even

```
CREATE TABLE Operations(
  ID INT IDENTITY(1, 1),
  Operation VARCHAR(45)
);

INSERT INTO Operations VALUES
('10-1'),
('10+1'),
('(5+5) - 5'),
('5+5');

DECLARE @SQL NVARCHAR(MAX) = N'SELECT ';

SELECT @SQL = @SQL + Operation + ' ,'
FROM Operations

SET @SQL = LEFT(@SQL, LEN(@SQL) - 1);

EXECUTE sp_executesql @SQL;
```

Or if you want to get it as rows

```
SELECT @SQL = @SQL + Operation + ' UNION ALL SELECT '
FROM Operations

SET @SQL = LEFT(@SQL, LEN(@SQL) - 17);

EXECUTE sp_executesql @SQL;
```

You can also declare the `@SQL` variable as follow if you want to name the column

```
DECLARE @SQL NVARCHAR(MAX) = N'SELECT Operations = ';
```

**[Demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=da726ae9f83f5ad7955d65c90a064710)**

As a final note (or warning), **be careful for SQL Injection** if your column has other strings as it maybe malicious commands.

Answer (score 0):

you can try like below, separate both  part by using substring  then 
convert it into int then add both

```
SELECT convert(int, substring('11-1',0, charindex('-', '11-1')))+
convert(int, substring('11-1',charindex('-', '11-1'), len('11-1')))
```

It will return 10

Comment: You have to think, will that work for other arithmetic equations though...? The OP may have more equations and not just a subtraction.

Comment: @arahman i answered according to sample as there no other description and my answer met the op's requirement. am i wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Use dynamic SQL to parse expression

```
DECLARE @result int, @sql nvarchar(max);
SET @sql = N'SELECT ' + '11 - 1';
EXEC sp_executesql @sql
```

or

```
DECLARE @result int, @sql nvarchar(max);
SET @sql = N'SELECT @result = ' + '11 - 1';
EXEC sp_executesql @sql, N'@result int OUTPUT', @result = @result OUTPUT
SELECT @result
```

This will return `10`

Answer (score 0):

The example below shows how you could evaluate the T-SQL expression stored in a table column. However, I would advise against this approach unless the value is from a source that is fully trusted. Otherwise, there is a SQL injection risk.

Also, this method cannot be used easily to return values from multiple rows in a single result. You would need a cursor to evaluate and insert each result into a temp table/variable and then select from the table as the final result.

```
DECLARE @Foo TABLE(
      FooID int
    , Expression nvarchar(10) NOT NULL
    )
INSERT INTO @Foo VALUES(1, '11-1');
DECLARE @sql nvarchar(MAX) = N'SELECT ' + (SELECT Expression FROM @foo WHERE FooID = 1) + N' AS Result;';
EXECUTE (@sql);
```